# Run md5sum shell command and save the output in C

Tags: c, shell

I'm trying to run a md5sum command and save the output in C, what is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: It is a good habit to search stack overflow before you post something here. Not voting down though because it is your #SOFirstTime

Answer (score 1):

[S.Iquebal deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243143/841108) is giving the right way. Use some *library functions* to compute the `md5sum` (without running any command) - see [md5 openssl functions](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/md5.html), since running a command has some overhead.

If you insist on running a command, run it with [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) or do the equivalent `pipe` + `fork` + `execve` [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)